# How to get and set property in JSNI using GWT?

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

**I have javascript code for get and set property :**

```
 set page(val) { some code.. },

 get page() { return currentPageNumber; },
```

Now i want to use these get and set property in JSNI but an error occur(JavaScript parsing: Missing : after property id) . plz suggest what can i do now???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSNI code is parsed using (a rather old version of) [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino), which doesn't support most of ECMAScript 5. You therefore cannot use ECMAScript 5 syntax, such as the `get` and `set` operators, within JSNI methods.

Comment: ok. If we are not able to use set and get property than with in function Object.defineProperty(object, propertyname, descriptor) use in JSNI or not?

Comment: AFAICT, `defineProperty` doesn't introduce any new **syntax**, so it should work… in browsers that support it!

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to set and get property in java script when we use js in java through JSNI.